# How to return the exception stack trace to normal, when using win32console gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, windows-console

- ruby 1.8.7 (2010-12-23 patchlevel 330) [i386-mingw32]
- win32console (1.3.2 x86-mingw32)
- wirble (0.1.3)
- Windows 7

I've recently started using wirble to colorize my irb output and read that I needed to have the win32console gem to actually have color, otherwise I get color codes.

That has worked well until I noticed that my exception stack trace looked different and was missing information.  I've narrowed it down to win32console.

Simple example without win32console:

```
irb(main):001:0> 1/0
ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0
        from (irb):1:in `/'
        from (irb):1
        from C:/ruby193/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

Simple example with win32console:

```
irb(main):003:0> 1/0
#<Class:0x57a7598>: divided by 0
        from (irb):3:in `/'
        from (irb):3
irb(main):004:0>
```

Is there a way to change it back but keep the colored output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out this issue has been logged before and I guess never added to the actual gem see [here](https://github.com/luislavena/win32console/issues/7) since the posts are four years old.

Basically change a line `s = t.dup.to_s` to `s = t.to_s.dup` in `lib\Win32\Console\ANSI.rb` in the `def _PrintString(t)` method.